# How to fix "Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'" with queryBuilder?

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder

I have a problem with a query i did, when i try to make a subquery i have this error message

```
"hydra:description": "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 85: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'",
```

for this query in my EventRepositoty CLass:

```
public function updateMoveAtField(string $eventLabel, $cameraId)
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
    $subQueryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('ev');

    $subQuery = $subQueryBuilder
        ->select('MAX(ev.arrivedAt) as arrived')
        ->andWhere('ev.camera = ?1')
        ->setParameter(1, $cameraId)
        ->getQuery()->getDQL()
    ;

    $event = $queryBuilder
        ->update()
        ->set('e.moveAt', '?1')
        ->where('e.label = ?2')
        ->andWhere('e.camera = ?3')
        ->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->andX($subQuery))
        ->setParameter(1, new \DateTime())
        ->setParameter(2, $eventLabel)
        ->setParameter(3, $cameraId);

    return $event->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

how can i fix it?

I dont know if you can understand my request so let me explain : i want to update a fiel "moveAt" when the label & camera its the same ones that were sent in the query. so i did a subquery because i want and other condition who are (always update the last one). i do a subquery because i can't add a select in a Update query.

EDIT :
Result of DQL dump from @Preciel help

> "SELECT MAX(e.arrivedAt) FROM App\Entity\Event e WHERE e.label=:var2
>   AND e.camera=:var3 AND e.camera=:var3 AND (e.arrivedAt <= SELECT
>   MAX(e.arrivedAt) FROM App\Entity\Event e WHERE e.label=:var2 AND
>   e.camera=:var3 AND e.camera=:var3)"

new =

> "UPDATE App\Entity\Event e SET event.moveAt = :var1 WHERE
>   e.label=:var2 AND e.camera=:var3 AND e.arrivedAt <= SELECT
>   MAX(ev.arrivedAt) FROM App\Entity\Event ev WHERE ev.camera=:var3"

subquery

> "SELECT MAX(ev.arrivedAt) FROM App\Entity\Event ev WHERE
>   ev.camera=:var3"

Comment: are `e` and `ev` from same entity/table?

Comment: Yes its the same entity

Comment: `->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->andX($subQuery))`: The `expr()` isn't needed here. And to which parameter do you want to compage your sub query? I'm excepting something like `->andWhere("e.parameter = $subQueryResult")`

Comment: i would like to compare it with 'e.arrivedAt or ev.arrivedAt', so when i try your  code after i edit it in my way , i have "SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "move_at" of relation "event" does not existLINE 1: UPDATE event SET move_at = $1 WHERE label = $2 AND" i dont know why, this part work when i dont use the subquery, and its a problem if my subquery return a array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to do something like this :

```
public function updateMoveAtField($eventLabel, $cameraId) {
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder("event");
    $sqb=$this->createQueryBuilder("eventBis");

    $qb->update()
       ->set("event.moveAt", ":var1")
       ->andWhere("event.lavel=:var2")
       ->andWhere("event.camera=:var3")
       ->andWhere(
           $qb->expr()->lte("event.arrivedAt",
               "(".$sqb->select($qb->expr()->max("eventBis.arrivedAt"))  //Your sub query start here
                   ->andWhere("eventBis.camera=:var3")->getDQL().")")) //and end here
       ->setParameters(array(
           'var1'=>new \DateTime(),
           'var2'=>$eventLabel,
           'var3'=>$cameraId,
       ));

    // dump($qb->getDQL());
    // dump($qb->getQuery()->getSQL());
    // exit();

    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

I added 2 lines of dump. if it doesn't works, please dump the DQL first, and the SQL (SQL might fail), and add them in comment please.

In the first use of `expr()`, I used `lte()` (less than or equal).
Change it to your needs (gt(), gte(), eq(), lte(), lt()).

**Tips :**

- Always use double quote for your query. Doctrine will only accept single quote for string value (single quote is fine for parameters).
- Never use `where()`, always start with `andWhere()` or `orWhere()`
- Avoir to use `andWhere()` and `orWhere()` together. Prefer `expr()` ([read more here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-queries/and-where-or-where))
- Avoid to mix DQL with pseudo-native (`LIKE`, `IN`, etc) SQL. Doctrine will chew you if it read some native SQL it can't use. Use `expr()` instead. If you can't find what you need in `expr()`, it mean you should create a native query.
- Fully name your alias, easier to read afterward.

**[EDIT]**

This is a screenshot of the dumped query given from my answer.
I think you tried to adapt my query to your code instead of just copy/paste it. Aliases don't match what I wrote in my query.

[image]

Aside from the aliases, we can see that a pair of parentheses is missing around the sub query. Just added them in my answer. If you copy/paste my code, it should, hopefully, solve your problem.

Comment: thank you, i edited my Question to see the response of the DQL dump, the SQL one failed. do you thing querybuilder/dql is good to do a subquery? like that ? or for the type of subquery its only in SQL native ? because for the moment it does not work, i still have the same error message

Comment: Sorry @Imrickjames, was busy doing something else, forgot to answer. I edited my answer. I added an extra query builder ($sqb) for the sub query. Can you try with that and dump the DQL/SQL if any error plz?

Comment: don't worry thanks for the time you give me, i still have the same error. did you think that can work with queryBuilder? I edited

Comment: @Imrickjames are you using the code as I wrote it? Or are you're adapting it with your code? Because there are a few alias that don't match, that shouldn't be the case with my query. I edited my answer to match the missing part. You should just have to copy/past.

Comment: thank you, you were right that was the problem and i didnt have this message error again ;), but my request still update update all events who have the same label and the same camera and not The last one arrived

Comment: @Imrickjames change `lte()` by `eq()` it will update teh last one only

Comment: thank you so much for all this help, my problem is solved now ;)